# Are the controls for RT-PCR the same as those for RT-qPCR?

Tags: gene-expression, pcr, reverse-transcription

I am searching for negative and positive controls for RT-PCR but all the results seem to point towards RT-qPCR. Are the controls the same for both?

I have found

1. -RT control
2. No template control
3. exogenous control
4. endogenous control
5. no amplification control

Do they apply for both or just RT-qPCR?

Comment: Those acronyms get slung around a lot with slightly different definitions.  RT = reverse-transcription and q = quantitative?

Comment: @Punintended yes, that's what they mean to my knowledge. but since the steps differ in both these methods I was wondering if the same controls applied to both.